# How to build a trail of nodes from a path in tikz-pgf?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, paths

What I want:

[image: Path to nodes with intersections]

where the yellow line is the path to be transformed. The points inside the yelow line are the nodes after processing.

The only way I found to do this is the intersection between a path and itself. But it is an expensive solution in terms of processing and time. The code to generate the above image is here:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 

        \clip (-2.1, -1.1) rectangle (2.1, 1.1);
        \draw [yellow, ultra thick, name path = curve 1] (-2,-1) .. controls (8,-1) and (-8,1) .. (2,1);

        \path [name intersections = {%
            of = curve 1 and curve 1
            , name = i
            , total=\t
            , sort by = curve 1
        }] node {\xdef\totalone{\t}};

        \foreach \k in {1, ..., \totalone}
        {
            \node [
                circle
                , fill
                , inner sep = 0.25pt
                , minimum size = 0pt
            ] at (i-\k) {};
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Someone suggests another way of doing this?

Comment: If you just want a black line through those nodes you can do: `\draw [dotteddecoration = black, yellow, ultra thick][postaction={draw,black,thin}] (-2,-1) .. controls (8,-1) and (-8,1) .. (2,1);` I am not quite sure, I know what your “big” goal is.

Comment: My goal is to find optimized ways to create addressable points along paths. I really liked your proposal! I wonder if there are other ways to do this.

Comment: Given the four control points you can express the Bezier curve as a parameterized curve. Then for each value of the parameter you can plot a point on the curve. I don't know exactly how to do it with TikZ but it must be doable :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to check out the `decorations.markins` library.
(Adjust the step between dots (`.5mm`) and the radius of the dots (`.25pt`) as you wish.

## Update

With this update you have the nodes `(node0)` to `(node203)`, `\themynodes` gives you 204.
(It can start from 1 and end with 204, if you put `\stepcounter{mynodes}` before the `\node` command.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\newcounter{mynodes}

\tikzset{dotteddecoration/.style={
    postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=between positions 0 and 1 step .5mm with {
                \node[text=black,font=\fontsize{5}{5}\selectfont] (node\themynodes) at (0,0) {\themynodes};\stepcounter{mynodes}}
}}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \clip (-2.1, -1.1) rectangle (2.1, 1.1);
        \draw [dotteddecoration, yellow, ultra thick] (-2,-1) .. controls (8,-1) and (-8,1) .. (2,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output: Update]

## Old solution

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{dotteddecoration/.style={
    postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=between positions 0 and 1 step .5mm with {
                \fill[#1] (0,0) circle (.25pt);}}}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \clip (-2.1, -1.1) rectangle (2.1, 1.1);
        \draw [dotteddecoration=black, yellow, ultra thick] (-2,-1) .. controls (8,-1) and (-8,1) .. (2,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: I thought the OP wanted to get a list of nodes that correspond to points on the path -- perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: It's a much more optimized way of doing what I was trying to do. I'll edit my question with an adapted version of this response and wait a bit to see if someone has another good suggestion. Thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel.

Comment: @PeterGrill He can still do … I'll update the answer.

Comment: @tecepe Instead of a counter, you could also use `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}` which is incremented for every node.