# Path following color gradient in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, gradient

How can I get a path following color gradient in TikZ? Here a quick example of the idea. On the left the result I'm looking for and on the right an example of a *non* path following gradient applied on a path.

[image: path following shading]

It looks like the TikZ shading library isn't covering this.

Related questions:

- [Tikz: Shading a path without any filling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134283/tikz-shading-a-path-without-any-filling).
- [Fading a path in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5107/fading-a-path-in-tikz)
- [How to draw an arrow with two colors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137357/how-to-draw-an-arrow-with-two-colors)

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of this one: [How would you draw an arrow filled with a gradient?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69429/4778)

Comment: @Alenanno I can't see how this gradient could follow a path (without major changes)

Comment: Oh, I see what you're asking now. Never mind then. :)

Comment: A combination of [Fading a path in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5107) (link 2) and [How to build a trail of nodes from a path in tikz-pgf?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75371) perhaps?

Comment: @someonr Would [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137438/4778) be the solution to your question? It shows paths with fading colors.

Comment: @Alenanno as far as I can see this won't solve this problem. Take a look at this result: http://i.stack.imgur.com/N4n1W.png I'll edit the question for easier understanding. If you think I could get a path following gradient with this, please give me a hint ;)

Comment: @someonr Uhm... you're right, that's *not* what you're looking for.

Comment: technically what you have is not a shading or fading in the PDF specifications sense. They operate on a layer where your path punches in so we see that layer thorough which is your image on the right. This is quite different in which you want the path to change color. So you are most probably better off with example given in the beginning of Part VII in the manual.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel this looks good (but a little slow), I'll post my results later

Answer (score 34):

Thanks to the hints from comments, I created the following proof of concept. This solution is not elegant (yet?) and slow.
[image: result]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}


\tikzset{test/.style={
    postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position \pgfdecoratedpathlength-0.5pt with {\arrow[blue,line width=#1] {>}; },
            mark=between positions 0 and \pgfdecoratedpathlength-8pt step 0.5pt with {
                \pgfmathsetmacro\myval{multiply(divide(
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/distance from start}, \pgfdecoratedpathlength),100)};
                \pgfsetfillcolor{blue!\myval!red};
                \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{#1};
                \pgfusepath{fill};}
}}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \path [test=2pt] (-1,-1) .. controls (9,-1) and (-7,1) .. (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A node is over-qualified for this. Rather use a path: `\fill[<color>] circle[radius=<radius>];`. It would probably be a little bit faster if you even use PGF for this, you will need at least `\pgfsetfillcolor`, `\pgfpathcircle` and `\pgfusepath{fill}` for that. By the way, inside of decorations, you should be able to access the path length via `\pgfdecoratedpathlength` or something alike.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I tried to use pgf for drawing, but I got http://i.stack.imgur.com/1AWwP.png (I'm not common with pgf). `\pgfdecoratedpathlength` works perfectly. Any idea for the arrow tip placement?

Comment: That’s strange. If I replace your `\fill`ed path with `\pgfsetfillcolor{blue!\myval!red}\pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{#1}\pgfusepath{fill}` I get the same result. I’d also replace `step 0.5pt` by `step .5*#1` so that the step length is scaled with (half) the line width. (The `2pt` is only half the line width because it is used as the radius of the circles, so the arrow tip is too small.) I don’t have any ideas on the arrow tip though, that is really annoying.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I was using `(0,0)` instead of `\pgfpointorigin`. Now it works.

Comment: You can replace `#1` by `.5\pgflinewidth` and any `0.5pt` by `.25\pgflinewidth` and then you can use it with usual line width. But if you say `\path [test, ultra thin] (-1,-1) .. controls (9,-1) and (-7,1) .. (1,1);` than it will run out of memory !

Comment: @someonr : Could you please check my question down? Thanks.

Comment: How would I change the argument 'blue!\myval!red' if I wanted to sample from a colormap instead?

Answer (score 29):

[image]

Here is a more complete answer -- still not perfect, and still slow, but at least is merges nicely with node borders:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}


\tikzset{test/.style n args={3}{
    postaction={
    decorate,
    decoration={
    markings,
    mark=between positions 0 and \pgfdecoratedpathlength step 0.5pt with {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\myval{multiply(
        divide(
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/distance from start}, \pgfdecoratedpathlength
        ),
        100
    )};
    \pgfsetfillcolor{#3!\myval!#2};
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{#1};
    \pgfusepath{fill};}
}}}}

\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0.2,0.8,0.3}
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0.8,0.3,0.2}
\definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.3,0.2,0.8}
\definecolor{c4}{rgb}{0.7,0.1,0.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    % node definitions
    \node [circle, draw=c1, ultra thick] (s1) at (0, 0) {s1};
    \node [circle, draw=c2, ultra thick] (s2) at (2, 1) {s2};
    \node [circle, draw=c3, ultra thick] (s3) at (-1, 3) {s3};
    \node [circle, draw=c4, ultra thick] (s4) at (-0.3, 5) {s4};

    % sketch
    \draw [test={0.8pt}{c1}{c2}, thick] (s1) to [bend right] (s2);
    \draw [test={0.8pt}{c1}{c3}, thick] (s1) to [bend left] (s3);
    \draw [test={1.2pt}{c2}{c3}, thick] (s2) to [bend left] (s3);
    \draw [test={0.9pt}{c3}{c4}, thick] (s2) to [bend right] (s4);
    \draw [test={1.1pt}{c2}{c4}, thick] (s3) to [bend right] (s4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```