# How can I draw an ellipse with a rainbow color?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I need to draw a rainbow-colored (hue colormap) ellipse in tikz.

Something like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26948/plotting-rainbow-circle) but then in an ellipse shape, and in tikz.

I've thought about drawing to ellipses, one with rainbox filling, the other white, but I don't know how to fill a shape with a rainbow.

I have looked at [questions relating to paths and colormaps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141378/path-following-color-gradient-in-tikz), but that won't do unless I really split the ellipse in many parts, which seems like it could be done a lot easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this OK?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[xscale=2]
        \clip (-2,0) rectangle (2,2);
        \shade[shading=color wheel] [even odd rule]
            (0,0) circle (2) (0,0) circle (1);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Remove the `\clip` if you want the full ellipse.

This was adapted from the shadings library example in the pgf manual.

[image]

Comment: Huh, I had already found the `shading=color wheel` option but it didn't work. Now it does. This is great, thanks! What does the `even odd rule` part actually do?

Comment: Simple answer: for a shape with a multi-path boundary (like an annulus/ring) it means you don't have to worry about the directions of the paths (clockwise/counterclockwise).   More complicated answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule