# Fading along a plot line in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm using the following code to draw the electron wavefunction around an atom. I'd like to fade out the line towards it's end. I've read all the relevant questions I can find, but I fail to get what I want.

Do you have any ideas?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,very thick]
\draw[color=red,domain=0:12.56,samples=200,smooth] plot (canvas polar cs:angle=\x r,radius={28-8*sin(2.25*\x r)});

\draw[dashed,domain=0:6.28,samples=200,smooth] plot (canvas polar
cs:angle=\x r,radius={0.5 r});
\draw[fill=black](0,0)circle (.5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is the end of the line in the output? Isn't it a closed shape line?

Comment: Not a closed shape, a polar plot between an angle of 0 and 4Pi.

Comment: You don't actually use any of the pgfplots functionality here, as far as I know (i.e. you have no `\addplot` and no `\begin{axis}`... Any reason to load pgfplots then?

Comment: Probably not now you mention it!

Comment: Have you read this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141378/path-following-color-gradient-in-tikz

Comment: Is there any way of getting this questions "bumped" so someone who can answer it might see it?