# Fading line with same color at both the ends

Tags: tikz-pgf, gradient

I wanted a fading line with the same color at both the ends and a second color in the middle. Here is the crude MWE I came up with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}                                                                       
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \path[left color=white,right color=black]
    (0,0) rectangle (.5\textwidth,.5pt);%
    \path[left color=black,right color=white]
    (.5\textwidth,0) rectangle (\textwidth,.5pt); 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This leaves a tiny tiny gap in the center. (Or is it just an optical illusion I get because I know I have used two path commands?)

Is there a better way of doing it? May be, with only one path/ fill/ rectangle command?

Comment: Did you read [Path following color gradient in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141378/14500)?

Comment: Did you try to fade your line using a single rectangle with a `middle color` key?

Comment: @PaulGaborit I had seen that conversation earlier. Too complex for a newbie like me :)

Comment: @PaulGaborit `middle color` was excellent. Looked up the exact syntax in `texdoc tikz` and done. Will you please give that comment as an answer? I will then accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the `middle color` key (*after* `right color` and `left color` keys):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}                                                                       
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \path[left color=white,right color=white,middle color=black]
    (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,.5pt);%
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```