# Smooth connections between segments of a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to replicate the following graph

[image]

My very manual attempt is not pretty since curves are not properly connected.

Some of you speak `path` and `controls` much better than I do. A litte help on these would be much appreciated.

**My question**

How can I get the blue and green parts to be "in the continuity" of the red one ?

**Edit**

As a consequence of this "smooth continuity, I would love to see how to apply a gradient color on the connected lines  [as in here] ([Path following color gradient in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141378/path-following-color-gradient-in-tikz))

[image]

[image]

My very manual MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[step=1.0,gray,thin] (0,0) grid (10,10);
    
    \node at (2,10) (nodeA) {A};
    
    \node at (10,2) (nodeB) {B};

    \node at (4.7,3.2) (nodeC) {C};
    
    \node at (10,3.2) (nodeD) {D};

    \node at (3,5.2) (nodeE) {E};

    \node at (0.5,6.5) (nodeF) {F};

    \draw[red,ultra thick, bend right=45, looseness=1.2] (nodeA) to (nodeB);
    
    \draw[green,ultra thick, bend right=1] (nodeC) to (nodeD);

    \draw[blue,ultra thick, bend right=30, looseness=1.2] (nodeE) to (nodeF);

    \draw [<->,thick] (0,10) node (yaxis) [left,rotate=90] {Bond price}
    |- (10,0) node (xaxis) [below] {Bond yield};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general problem using `node`s like you do it, that they containg inner spacing, so it is often advisable to use `coordinate`s which are just points. For the rest it is bascially just using the `to` sytnax with entrance and exit angles `in` and `out`. I also used `intersections` to ensure E and C are on the line from A to B, but that is just a detail and can be achieved manually as well.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,every node/.style={text=black}]
        \draw[step=1.0,gray,thin] (0,0) grid (10,10);
        \coordinate (D) at (10,2.8);
        \coordinate (F) at (0.5,6.5);
        
        \draw[red,ultra thick,looseness=1.2,name path=redline] (2,10) node[anchor=south] (A) {A} to[out=270,in=180] (10,2) node[anchor=west] (B){B};
        \path[name path=helpE] (0,5.2) -- ++(10,0);
        \path[name path=helpC] (0,4) -- ++(10,0); 
        \path [name intersections={of=redline and helpE,by=E}];
        \path [name intersections={of=redline and helpC,by=C}];
    
        \draw[green,ultra thick] (C) node[anchor=south]{C} to[out=325,in=180] (D) node[anchor=west]{D};
        \draw[blue,ultra thick] (F) node[anchor=south]{F} to[out=0,in=120] (E) node[anchor=west] {E};
        
        \draw [<->,thick] (0,10) node (yaxis) [anchor=south east,rotate=90] {Bond price}
        |- (10,0) node (xaxis) [anchor=north east] {Bond yield};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: You can of course combine this approach with the colour gradient question you linked to. I take no credit, this is simply copy-paste and apply:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,decorations.markings}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background, main}

\tikzset{test/.style n args={3}{
        postaction={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=between positions 0 and \pgfdecoratedpathlength step 0.4pt with {
                    \pgfmathsetmacro\myval{multiply(
                        divide(
                        \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/distance from start}, \pgfdecoratedpathlength
                        ),
                        100
                        )};
                    \pgfsetfillcolor{#3!\myval!#2};
                    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{#1};
                    \pgfusepath{fill};}
}}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,every node/.style={text=black}]
        \draw[step=1.0,gray,thin] (0,0) grid (10,10);
        \coordinate (D) at (10,2.8);
        \coordinate (F) at (0.5,6.5);
        
        
        \draw[red,ultra thick,looseness=1.2,name path=redline] (2,10) node[anchor=south] (A) {A} to[out=270,in=180] (10,2) node[anchor=west] (B){B};
        
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \path[name path=helpE] (0,5.2) -- ++(10,0);
            \path[name path=helpC] (0,4) -- ++(10,0); 
            \path [name intersections={of=redline and helpE,by=E}];
            \path [name intersections={of=redline and helpC,by=C}];
            
            \draw[test={0.8pt}{red}{green},ultra thick] (C) node[anchor=south]{C} to[out=325,in=180] (D) node[anchor=west]{D};
            \draw[test={0.8pt}{blue}{red},,ultra thick] (F) node[anchor=south]{F} to[out=0,in=120] (E) node[anchor=west] {E};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    
        \draw [<->,thick] (0,10) node (yaxis) [anchor=south east,rotate=90] {Bond price}
        |- (10,0) node (xaxis) [anchor=north east] {Bond yield};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And just because I think it makes more sense to put the branches behind the main line, I added some layers.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! It works great. You were so fast I did not have time to amend and precise my question. I updated it regarding a color gradient at the connection points. If you don't mind, i'll wait a bit to validate your answer :)

Comment: As per your request I added a possible combination of my answer with the one you linked to. It is for sure not perfect, but if you want a smoother gradient it is going to be a lot more complicated for sure.

Comment: Perfect, Looks great.