# Path double color gradient in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I am trying to draw a path with a double color gradient, first magenta to cyan then cyan to magenta.

I have tried to use the code from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141378/path-following-color-gradient-in-tikz) thread, but the best I could do is this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}


\tikzset{multicolor/.style={
        postaction={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=between positions 0 and 0.5*\pgfdecoratedpathlength step 0.5pt with {
                    \pgfmathsetmacro\myval{multiply(divide(
                        \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/distance from start}, 1*\pgfdecoratedpathlength),200)};
                    \pgfsetfillcolor{cyan!\myval!magenta};
                    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{#1};
                    \pgfusepath{fill};},
                mark=between positions 0.5*\pgfdecoratedpathlength and \pgfdecoratedpathlength step 0.5pt with {
                    \pgfmathsetmacro\myval{300+multiply(divide(
                        \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/distance from start}, 1*\pgfdecoratedpathlength),200)};
                    \pgfsetfillcolor{magenta!\myval!cyan};
                    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{#1};
                    \pgfusepath{fill};},
}}}}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path [multicolor=0.3mm,draw] (0,0) .. controls (1,3) and (5,-7) .. (4,1)  {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    
\end{document}
```

which produces this:
[image]

I would like the second part of the path to gradually change from cyan to magenta.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an adjustment to the formula.

I've also added `overlay` to the path itself so that the bounding box does not include the control points but `\pgf@relevantforpicturesizetrue` (i.e. `overlay = false`) so that the circles themselves are counted towards the bounding box of the picture.

The path itself is not drawn and the `multicolor` style does not include `postaction` anymore because the line would be hidden by the circles anyway.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  multicolor/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=between positions 0 and 0.5*\pgfdecoratedpathlength step 0.5pt with {
        \csname pgf@relevantforpicturesizetrue\endcsname % overlay = false
        \pgfmathparse{multiply(divide(
          \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/distance from start},
          \pgfdecoratedpathlength),200)}
        \pgfsetfillcolor{cyan!\pgfmathresult!magenta}
        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{#1}
        \pgfusepath{fill}},
      mark=between positions 0.5*\pgfdecoratedpathlength and
        \pgfdecoratedpathlength step 0.5pt with {
        \csname pgf@relevantforpicturesizetrue\endcsname % overlay = false
        \pgfmathparse{subtract(multiply(divide(
          \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/distance from start},
          \pgfdecoratedpathlength),200),100)}
        \pgfsetfillcolor{magenta!\pgfmathresult!cyan}
        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{#1}
        \pgfusepath{fill}}}}}

\begin{document}
\tikz % overlay because of control points
  \path[multicolor=0.3mm, overlay] (0,0) .. controls (1,3) and (5,-7) .. (4,1);
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: amazing, thanks!!